# deploying from git to open shift giving 404 not found

Tags: git, openshift

i am using wildfly image in openshift, when i deploy a sample application from my desktop through oc commands its working fine, but when it try to push from github same code its showing 404 not found error. pom file is below

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>SampleServices</groupId>
      <artifactId>SampleServices</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <name>Get</name>

         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>2.25.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Required only when you are using JAX-RS Client -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>2.25.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <profiles>
        <profile>
        <id>openshift</id>
      <build>
     <!--    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
        <finalName>SampleServices</finalName> 
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      </profile>
      </profiles>
    </project>
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual ``oc`` commands you are running? It is not clear as to what you are doing.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i dont have any issue when use OC command to deploy a build through oc command. but when the same files push to github, and from github to opnshift build deployment iam not getting my files on the browser showing 404 not found. and last the oc command what iam using for deployment " oc start-build mysample --from-file=sample"